# print statement with time interval and in one line

Tags: python

does anyone know in python  how to print a character 10 times so that there is a 1 second gap between printing each character and the characters are printed in one line and not in the next line?

This is my code but it doesn't work properly

```
import time
s=0
while(s!=0):
    print('a', end="")             
    time.sleep(1)
    s+=1
```

Comment: Think carefully about what `while s!=0:` means. At what points is that expression evaluated, and what happens when it is true or false?

Comment: It seems like a `for` loop would be more appropriate here, don't you think?

Answer (score 0):

You could use any() with a comprehension, but why not a for-loop ?

```
from time import sleep
S = "hello world"

any(print(c,end="") or sleep(1) for c in S)
```